# Does multiple definitions of object of lambda expression in different translation units violate the ODR in C++?

Tags: c++, lambda, one-definition-rule

I thought the following codes violates ODR (`f` is defined in both foo.cpp and main.cpp), but the compiler yields no error.

```
// foo.h
auto f = [](int i){return i;};
void printTypeID();

// foo.cpp
#include "foo.h"
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

void printTypeID(){
    std::cout << typeid(f).name() << '\n';
}

// main.cpp
#include "foo.h"
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << typeid(f).name() << '\n';
    printTypeID();
    return 0;
}
```

And the output typeid is identical, which surprises me because I thought every lambda expression will have an unique non-union class type unless they are in the body of external inline function definition.

---

**Edit:** As I'm looking into the standard, I intend to think that this is because objects of unnamed class type have internal linkage. Although I haven't found the corresponding specification. These are related specification I have found below.

The type of lambda expression is a unique, unnamed non-union class type: [expr.prim.lambda](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#4)

> The type of the lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, **unnamed non-union class** type — called the closure type — whose properties are described below. [...]

A unnamed class type that has global scope has no linkage, but, a type with no linkage still could be used to declare an object with external linkage. [basic.link](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#8)

> Names not covered by these rules have no linkage. Moreover, except as noted, a name declared at block scope ([basic.scope.block]) has no linkage. A **type** is said to have linkage **if and only if**:
>
> - it is a class or enumeration type that is named (or has a name for linkage purposes ([dcl.typedef])) and the name has linkage; or
> - it is an unnamed class or unnamed enumeration that is a member of a class with linkage; or
> - it is a specialization of a class template (Clause [temp])34; or
> - it is a fundamental type ([basic.fundamental]); or
> - it is a compound type ([basic.compound]) other than a class or enumeration, compounded exclusively from types that have linkage; or
> - it is a cv-qualified ([basic.type.qualifier]) version of a type that has linkage.
>
> A type without linkage shall not be used as the type of a variable or function with external linkage unless
>
> - the entity has C language linkage ([dcl.link]), or
> - the entity is declared within an unnamed namespace ([namespace.def]), or
> - the entity is not odr-used ([basic.def.odr]) or **is defined in the same translation unit**.

And the object of the lambda expression (`f` in this case) is NOT a variable that has internal linkage according to following quotations: [basic.link](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#3)

> A name having namespace scope ([basic.scope.namespace]) has internal linkage if it is the name of
>
> - a variable, function or function template that is explicitly declared static; or,
> - a non-inline variable of non-volatile const-qualified type that is neither explicitly declared extern nor previously declared to have external linkage; or
> - a data member of an anonymous union.
>
> An unnamed namespace or a namespace declared directly or indirectly within an unnamed namespace has internal linkage. All other namespaces have external linkage. A name having namespace scope that has not been given internal linkage above has the same linkage as the enclosing namespace if it is the name of [...]

So, the output typeids in previous codes might be identical, and it's not a problem here since the closure type in this case has no linkage. But the question comes to:

Do objects of unnamed class type that have global scope have internal linkage?

Comment: The type of f is not the same, lambdas are unnamed, so there is no ODR violation

Comment: @paulm `auto f` is not unique (regardless if it is a lambda or not)

Comment: @paulm whether the types of the lambdas are same or not, we use same identity `f` here which violates the ODR. As if we define `int a` in foo.cpp while define `float a` in main.cpp

Comment: I don't understand your question. You raise undefined behavior, then you ask "why do I get this behavior from undefined behavior? shouldn't it be that behavior?"

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I was expecting the compiler to tell me that there are multiple definition of `f` just as what he does when I write `int i = 1;` in foo.h